How does copyright work when creating a graphic design with photos of celebrities/artists?
I’m getting into graphic design and I’m also a photographer for local bands. I want to make designs that revolve around music and I’m wondering, for bigger artists, ones I haven’t photographed myself, do I need to track down who took the photos and get their permission?
How does this work in terms of copyright and do most designers reach out to photographers? I see designs revolving around musicians all the time and I doubt everyone is asking for permission but maybe I’m wrong. I’m curious and would like to keep myself out of trouble as well as respect other people’s work.

Royalty free.. you can't use anything you don't have permission to use.

Disclaimer: This is not legal advice. Also, laws differ by country. So, if you want legal advice, hire a lawyer in your own part of the world.
Most graphic designers use stock photography sites to purchase licences to use photographs. If it's a celebrity image, the go-to site is probably Getty Images. Chances are that any half decent photo of them you find online is probably already owned by Getty, as they kind of dominate the market worldwide. However, they (and most stock image sites) won't sell a licence for commercial use of such images [*see Note below]: for example selling/endorsing products/services. In such cases you'd need to reach out to the celebrity themselves and work out a deal with them, most likely via their agent.  This is not something a graphic designer would normally get involved with TBH, something a client would negotiate with the celebrity long before the graphic designer takes on the job.
Sure, people do illegal stuff with celebrity photos all the time, but some of them also get caught and sued [*see Note 2 below].
*Note Some countries such as the US give celebrities more rights/control on use of their images for commercial purposes, which is why most stock photography sites won't even sell such licences for celebrity images.
*Note 2 There are some countries (including mine, the UK) where celebrities have more limited rights to their images. However, even here there has been at least one high level court case in which a music celebrity successfully sued over use of their image on a T-shirt sold without their permission. It cost the fashion retailer £3.3 million GBP ($5 million USD), even though the retailer claimed they had a licence to use the image. Link to BBC News article
Copyright laws can sometimes swing the other way when it comes to celebrities and their images, especially if they assume they have rights to images they they don't actually own. This recent case is interesting.
TLDR: it's a legal minefield, best avoided at all costs, unless you have big pockets, or a deal already set up with a celebrity.
